# Extract string numbers of text with various delimiters

Tags: linux, bash, scripting

I need to extract the numbers the following lines, these are all possibilities you can find me, are characterized in the first comma after the string to be extracted.

```
SIP/6599595,,tr
SIP/Core-out/6641150,30
8000,,
SIP/Ar2-1-out/6641150,30
```

The output should be:

```
6599595
6641150
8000
6641150
```

The method is in BASH.

Comment: So is it the first number that you find on each line? Have you tried anything? Do you require a native bash solution or would using a tool such as awk be acceptable?

Comment: With awk would be acceptable, no problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
grep -oP '(/|^)\K[0-9]+'
```

Output:

```
6599595
6641150
8000
6641150
```

Answer (score 2):

quick and dirty:

```
grep -Po '\d+(?=,)'
```

with your data:

```
kent$ echo "SIP/6599595,,tr
SIP/Core-out/6641150,30
8000,,
SIP/Ar2-1-out/6641150,30"|grep -Po '\d+(?=,)'
6599595
6641150
8000
6641150
```

Answer (score 2):

This awk script produces the desired output:

```
$ awk -F'[,/]' '{for(i=1;i<=NF;++i)if($i~/^[0-9]+$/){print $i; next}}' file.txt
```

Set the input field separator to commas or slashes. Loop through each field and print the first one that contains only digits.

Answer (score 1):

Couple of piped seds will sort you out too.

```
sed -e 's/^.*\///' -e 's/\,.*$//' file
```

#### Test

```
# cat arg.txt
SIP/6599595,,tr
SIP/Core-out/6641150,30
8000,,
SIP/Ar2-1-out/6641150,30
# sed -e 's/^.*\///' -e 's/\,.*$//' arg.txt
6599595
6641150
8000
6641150
```

Comment: Note `sed '...' arg.txt` is the same as `cat arg.txt | sed '...'`.

Comment: Absolutely true. You could also use sed -i to directly edit the file.